# Map Ctrl+c to one button to stop a script on terminal

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, button, remapping

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I wanted to remap the functionality of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to just one button (e.g b) such that whenever I press that button in terminal it forces the script running in it to stop (kinda break), can you please tell me how is this possible?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stty intr b` Will make the b key send an interrupt like control c.

Take a look at `man stty` for setting up/changing terminal settings like that.